# Double quotes in single quotes from table

Tags: php, mysql, quote

In my table i have query:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `jom_x1_organizatori` 
      WHERE Organizator='".$sta_dalje."' Order by `Struka`,`Zanimanje`";
```

`$sta_dalje`=$_POST["state_id"] from another table and value is:

1. ЈУ Гимназија са техничким школама Дервента
2. "ПРИМУС" Градишка

In case 1 working.

How to make query?

Comment: You need to escape the double quote using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.. Or better use PDO or Mysqli with prepared statement.

Comment: Though escaping is good practice and will stop SQL injections, the example you are giving needs no escaping to work. Double quotes in single quotes need no escaping. It is single quotes in single quotes or double quotes in double quotes that need escaping.

Comment: Which extension do you use currently mysql,mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firts of all: Never build the query by concatenating the query string with user input! If you do, then escape the input with the library's dedicated function (`mysqli_real_escape_string` for example). Without escaping you will open a potential security hole (called [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

`"ПРИМУС" Градишка` is not working because after concatenating, the query will be invalid. Now imagine, what happens, if I post the following input: `'; DROP TABLE jom_x1_organizatori; --`

Your query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM `jom_x1_organizatori` 
      WHERE Organizator=''; DROP TABLE jom_x1_organizatori; --' Order by `Struka`,`Zanimanje`
```

Whenever you can use `prepared statements` to bind parameters (and let the library to do the hard work), but always escape and validate your input (using prepared statements, escaping is done by the library)!

```
$sta_dalje = (sting)$_POST["state_id"]; // Do filtering, validating, force type convertation, etc!!

// Prepare the statement (note the question mark at the end: it represents the parameter)
$stmt = $mysqlLink->mysqli_prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM `jom_x1_organizatori` WHERE Organizator = ?"
);

// Bind a string parameter to the first position
$stmt->bind_param("s", $sta_dalje);
```

For more info about prepared statements:

- [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
- [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Please note that the old `mysql` extension is deprecated, do not use it if not necessary!

**Just a side note**

Do not use `SELECT * FROM`, always list the columns. It prevents to query unnecessary data and your code will be more resistant to database changes, plus debugging will be a bit simplier task.

Answer (score 0):

Use escape string

```
$sta_dalje = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["state_id"]);
```

And your where condition can be simply

```
 Organizator='$sta_dalje'
```

Comment: Sorry, $sta_dalje=$_POST["state_id"]